# Параллельное выполнение быстрой сортировки

Tags: c++, алгоритм, многопоточность, qsort

Вот есть такая реализация быстрой сортировки:

```
template<class iterator>
void qsort(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
    if (begin == end)
        return;

    const auto distance = std::distance(begin, end);
    iterator p = std::next(begin, distance / 2);
    iterator it1 = std::partition(begin, end, [&p](const auto& v){ return v < *p;});
    iterator it2 = std::partition(it1, end, [&p](const auto& v) { return !(v > *p);});

    qsort(begin, it1);
    qsort(it2,  end);
}
```

Я хочу реализовать паралельное выполнение этого алгоритма. Можно конечно сделать так:

```
template<class iterator>
void qsort(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
    if (begin == end)
        return;

    const auto distance = std::distance(begin, end);
    iterator p = std::next(begin, distance / 2);
    iterator it1 = std::partition(begin, end, [&p](const auto& v){ return v < *p;});
    iterator it2 = std::partition(it1, end, [&p](const auto& v) { return !(v > *p);});

    std::thread t1(qSort<Iterator>, begin, middle1);
    std::thread t2(qSort<Iterator>, middle2, end);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

но это очевидно далеко не лучшая реализация т.к. количество потоков будет равно `log(n)`.

Вопрос: как правильно реализовать многопоточный алгоритм быстрой сортировки? Можно написать класс который будет лимитировать количество потоков и передавать его в функцию, но стандартная реализация `std::sort` может выполняться в нескольких потоков, при этом ее сигнатура не меняется, хотелось бы реализовать что-то подобное.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтоб решить проблему именно с сигнатурами функцию с дополнительным параметром просто не показывайте пользователю, а функция, которой должен пользоваться клиент должна быть с такой же сигнатурой как и сейчас:

```
template<class iterator>
void qsort(iterator begin, iterator end)
{
  qsort_internal(begin, end, 4);
}

template<class iterator>
void qsort_internal(iterator begin, iterator end, int max_threads)
{

  ...
  if (max_threads > 1) {
    //сортируем многопоточно
    // но уменьшаем max_threads в рекурсивном вызове
  } else {
    // сортируем в этом же потоке 
  }

}
```

Нужно понимать, что такая наивная реализация, скорее всего не даст особого прироста, а скорее всего будет медленее, на небольших массивах даже существенно медленнее. Поищите тут, неоднократно обсуждался вопрос и трудности связанные с ускорением алгоритмов путем параллелизации и в частности с ускорением быстрой сортировки.

Answer (score 4):

Для таких задач обычно используются пул потоков с фиксированным числом потоков [(одна из его реализаций)](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool), добавление задачи в пул по производительности в худшем случае эквивалентно блокировке мьютекса.

Стандартные реализации параллельных алгоритмов обычно использует скрытый от пользователя (глобальный) пул потоков. Или же OpenMP, реализация которого также использует пул потоков, но могут использовать какие-то дополнительные особенности платформы.

Можно найти примеры сортировки при помощи std::async, который также может использовать глобальный пул потоков. Но на практике реализации стандартных библиотек могут создавать новый поток вместо использования пула, из-за чего смысла в этом нет.

Если говорить конкретно о сортировке, у вас вряд ли получится приблизиться к стандартной реализации. Подобные алгоритмы вообще плохо распараллеливаются на ЦП, из-за чего для их реализации используется множество не очевидных приемов (и результат все-равно сомнительный).
Если вам действительно интересно ускорение сортировки - рекомендую смотреть в сторону GPU (thrust::sort, например).